# Proper jurisdiction for injunctive relief not involving a monetary claim in Boston

Tags: jurisdiction, massachusetts

I am trying to figure out the proper venue for petitioning a civil injunction, a complicated problem in Boston. The pleading is for a mandatory injunction against the directors of a corporation located in Boston which does not involve any monetary claims.

There are two possible venues: the Central Division of the Boston Municipal Court and the Suffolk County Superior Court.

I have read conflicting information. On one hand I have read that the Superior Court only hears cases involving claims over $25,000, however, I have also read that the the municipal court's jurisdiction only extends to cases cases involving monetary claims, and if a tort does not involve monetary damages, and only injunctive relief and does not fall into a special category (family, probate, etc), then it has Superior Court jurisdiction. Any opinions which it should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer**

The Superior Court is the court of general jurisdiction and the primary equity court will full authority over cases seeking injunctive relief. So, if the case does not fall into a category such as family court, probate court, or land court, the Superior Court is probably the correct court.

The District Court has limited equity jurisdiction, but the wording of the statute giving it equity jurisdiction is ambiguous and doesn't appear to divest the Superior Court of any authority, so the Superior Court is probably correct, although it is hard to know without more information. For example, Housing Court is part of District Court (i.e. Boston Municipal Court), and so injunctions relating to landlord-tenant issues might properly be brought in that court.

**Superior Court Jurisdiction**

Superior Court original civil jurisdiction (i.e. opposed to appellate or criminal jurisdiction), other than territorial jurisdiction (I am assuming that Boston is actually the right location for your claim without knowing what it is for sake of argument) is as follows:

> The court shall have exclusive original jurisdiction of civil actions
>   for the foreclosure of mortgages, and of real and mixed actions,
>   **except those of which the land court or district courts have
>   jurisdiction**, of complaints for flowing lands, and of claims against
>   the commonwealth. Except as otherwise provided by law, the court shall
>   have original jurisdiction of civil actions for money damages. The
>   actions may proceed in the court only if there is no reasonable
>   likelihood that recovery by the plaintiff will be less than or equal
>   to $25,000, or an amount ordered from time to time by the supreme
>   judicial court. Where multiple damages are allowed by law, the amount
>   of single damages claimed shall control.

Mass. Gen. Laws ch. 212, § 3.

> The court shall have original jurisdiction of all civil actions,
>   except those of which other courts have exclusive original
>   jurisdiction.

Mass. Gen. Laws ch. 212, § 4.

Also, in cases at equity, which would include suits for an injunction:

> The supreme judicial and superior courts shall have original and
>   concurrent jurisdiction of all cases and matters of equity cognizable
>   under the general principles of equity jurisprudence and, with
>   reference thereto, shall be courts of general equity jurisdiction,
>   except that the superior court shall have exclusive original
>   jurisdiction of all actions in which injunctive relief is sought in
>   any matter involving or growing out of a labor dispute as defined in
>   section twenty C of chapter one hundred and forty-nine.

Mass. Gen. Laws ch. 214, § 1.

The Supreme Judicial Court is the state supreme court in the state.

**District Court**

The territorial jurisdiction of the Boston Municipal Court is a bit odd:

> The municipal courts in Boston shall have concurrent jurisdiction over
>   all waters, islands and places not included in the district of any one
>   of said courts or of the district court of Chelsea, and within the
>   jurisdiction of the superior court for Suffolk county, except as
>   provided in the preceding and following sections.

Mass. Gen. Laws ch. 218, § 2

The general civil jurisdiction of the Boston Municipal Court which is a form of District Court is as follows:

> Except as otherwise provided by law, the district court and Boston
>   municipal court departments shall have original jurisdiction of civil
>   actions for money damages. The actions may proceed in the courts only
>   if there is no reasonable likelihood that recovery by the plaintiff
>   will exceed $25,000, or an amount ordered from time to time by the
>   supreme judicial court. Where multiple damages are allowed by law, the
>   amount of single damages claimed shall control. Notwithstanding the
>   limitation of $25,000, or other amount ordered by the supreme judicial
>   court, the district courts may proceed with actions for money damages
>   in any amount in summary process actions. The Boston municipal and
>   district court departments shall have original jurisdiction concurrent
>   with the probate and family court department of actions relative to
>   paternity and support under chapter two hundred and nine C. The
>   district courts shall also have jurisdiction of actions in summary
>   process under chapter two hundred and thirty-nine and in the hearing
>   and disposition of such actions shall have the same equitable powers
>   and jurisdiction as is provided for the divisions of the housing court
>   department pursuant to section three of chapter one hundred and
>   eighty-five C. The Boston municipal and district court departments
>   shall have original jurisdiction concurrent with the probate and
>   family court department of proceedings under chapter two hundred and
>   nine D. They shall have jurisdiction of proceedings transferred to
>   them under the provisions of section four A of chapter two hundred and
>   eleven.

Mass. Gen. Laws ch. 218, § 19.

The equitable powers of the Boston Municipal Court are as follows:

> The district court and Boston municipal court departments of the trial
>   court shall have the same equitable powers and jurisdiction as is
>   provided for the superior court pursuant to chapter 214 and the same
>   authority with regard to declaratory judgments as is provided for the
>   superior court pursuant to chapter 231A for the purpose of the hearing
>   and disposition of summary process actions and of civil actions for
>   money damages under section 19 of this chapter.
>
> The district courts shall have original jurisdiction in rem and
>   personam of all actions arising under sections one hundred and
>   twenty-seven A to one hundred and twenty-seven K, inclusive, of
>   chapter one hundred and eleven. **The district courts shall have equity
>   powers only to the extent necessary to enforce the aforementioned
>   sections, including the power to appoint receivers, grant injunctions
>   and issue restraining orders as justice and equity may require and for
>   punishing civil contempt of orders, rulings and decrees made or
>   pronounced in the exercise of this jurisdiction.**
>
> Subject to the approval of the supreme judicial court, the chief
>   justice for the district court department may from time to time
>   promulgate rules and prescribe forms for the efficient operation of
>   such equity sessions in the courts of the district court department;
>   and in the Boston municipal court department the chief justice for
>   said department may promulgate such rules and prescribe such forms.

Mass. Gen. Laws ch. 218, § 19C

Section 127 basically involves supervisory authority over jails.

Comment: So, to sum this up (ignoring irrelevant special areas like probate and housing), basically the municipal court is for money claims under $25,000 and the superior court is for injunctions not involving money OR cases involving over $25,000. That was my read. Is that your impression too?

Comment: There are lots of exceptions to the general rule, but yes, that does appear to be the general rule. (The MA court system is incredibly complex compared to CO where we have far fewer specialized courts.)